# How to make timeline with OpenLayers?

Tags: geoext, boundless-suite, openlayers-2

I have OL, GeoExt, gxp. I have a layer with Date attribute. So I want to show features with same date.

I found an [example](http://gxp.opengeo.org/master/examples/time-viewer.html) using `gxp_playback`, but it does not work because it can't find `OpenLayer.TimeUnit.HOURS`. I found some libraries that this example requires [there](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/mpriour/temporal_map/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/) but none contain `OpenLayer.TimeUnit`.

Am I searching for this in the wrong place? Or is this whole example bad and there is a simpler way to make timeline?

I found [gxp_timeline](http://gxp.opengeo.org/master/doc/lib/plugins/Timeline.html) in gxp docs but can't find any examples of how to use this.

Comment: May be useful for you https://github.com/volpino/openlayers-timeline

Comment: +1 Please check similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330122/openlayers-timeline-integration

Comment: @Sunil: Your example looks like what i want. I try to use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Please check timeline plugin on [GitHub](https://github.com/volpino/openlayers-timeline). I am sure it will help you.

It contains  simple library to create a time related map with Open Layers. It supports cluster strategy (Open Layers.Strategy.Cluster) and time filtering.

Currently it supports source data in GeoJSON or GeoRSS format.

Comment: Can i use this library if i create layer from parametric view on Geoserver (date is parameter)?

Comment: @Kliver Max not  sure but you can try. Similarly I will also check this at my end

Comment: After a long time. I am trying to implement this example. I have marker history with start and end time which I need to display in the map and remove from the map while it is playing the slider or manual drag the slider. I must able to select two days (ex: 2021-01-10 to 2021-02-05) markers are (name: "marker one", start: 2021-01-10 10:20:00, end: 2021-01-10 11:50:00), slider time gap should be 15 mins or as selected from input. Need help to implement this. Can you provide me a sample GEOJSON file for this requirement